# How to get access to widgets in kivy? I need to remove TextInput by pressing a Button

Tags: python, widget, kivy

How to get access to different widgets in python kivy?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class kxApp(App):
    def build(self):

        gl_main = GridLayout(rows=2,padding=5, spacing=5)

        gl_left = GridLayout(padding=5, spacing=5)
        gl_middle = GridLayout(padding=5, spacing=5)
        gl_right = GridLayout(padding=5, spacing=5)

        gl_main.add_widget(gl_left)
        gl_main.add_widget(gl_middle)
        gl_main.add_widget(gl_right)

        gl_left.add_widget(TextInput(text='Input Here'))
        gl_middle.add_widget(Label(text='Just Label'))
        gl_right.add_widget(Button(text='Remove Input Field', on_press killFunc))

    def killFunc(self,obj):
        #how to get access to TextInput() and remove it?

kxApp().run()
```

What is the natural way to 'get' widget to manipulate it?

Comment: You can save a reference to it by doing `self.text_input = TextInput(text='Input Here')` or you can build your app gui using `kv` and access widgets through the `ids` dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saving a reference to the `TextInput`, you can simply use `remove_widget`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class kxApp(App):
    def build(self):

        gl_main = GridLayout(rows=2,padding=5, spacing=5)

        gl_left = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=5, spacing=5)
        gl_middle = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=5, spacing=5)
        gl_right = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=5, spacing=5)

        gl_main.add_widget(gl_left)
        gl_main.add_widget(gl_middle)
        gl_main.add_widget(gl_right)

        self.text_input = TextInput(text='Input Here')
        gl_left.add_widget(self.text_input)
        gl_middle.add_widget(Label(text='Just Label'))
        gl_right.add_widget(Button(text='Remove Input Field', on_press=self.killFunc))

        return gl_main

    def killFunc(self,obj):
        self.text_input.parent.remove_widget(self.text_input)

kxApp().run()
```